# Nodejs Unhandled promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I keep getting "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)"

I have handled all promise but the error persists

```
    const router =require('express').Router();
const User = require('../modules/user');
const auth = require('../authenticate/auth');

router.post('/create', auth, async(req,res, next)=>{
    let uid = req.user.uid;
    try{
        await User.findById(uid)
        .then(user=>{
             user.Business.forEach(business => {
                 if(business._id == req.body.buId ){
                    console.log(business._id)
                    business.items.push(req.body);
                    user.save()
                    .then(user=>{
                        res.json(user);
                    },(err) => next(err))
                    .catch(err=>{
                        res.json({err})
                    })
                 }
                 else{
                    res.statusCode = 400;
                    res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
                    res.json({err, message:'no such business exist'})
                 }
             });  
        },(err) => next(err))
        .catch (err=>{
            res.json({err, message:'user do not exist'})
        })
    }
    catch (err){
        res.send(err)
    }

})

module.exports= router;
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the code you've included in the question. The only way I can see that the code above would result in an unhandled rejection would be if the `res.send(err)` in the `catch` block at the end or the `res.json({err})` in the rejection handler inside the `forEach` threw an error, and that seems unlikely to me.

Comment: perhaps in your `auth` callback...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you are using Promise in user.findById and user.save , you don't need the "async" and the "await" keyword . You are handling the error using .catch block.

Secondly, you are using a for Each loop which has promise inside it, it will not work. Use normal for loop or any other.

Comment: You can also omit the try catch block, the .catch block of findById is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently promise don't work well in loop functions. so stored it in avariable variable function.

```
const router =require('express').Router();
const User = require('../modules/user');
const auth = require('../authenticate/auth');

router.post('/create', auth, (req,res, next)=>{
    let uid = req.user.uid;
    try{
        User.findById(uid)
        .then(user=>{
             let business = ()=>{
                for (let index = 0; index < user.Business.length; index++) {
                   if(user.Business[index]._id == req.body.buId ){
                     return user.Business[index];
                   }
                }
            }
            business().items.push(req.body);
            user.save()
            .then(user=>{
                res.json(user);
            },(err) => next(err))
            .catch(err=>{
                res.json({err})
            })
        },(err) => next(err))
        .catch (err=>{
            res.json({err, message:'user do not exist'})
        })
    }
    catch (err){
        res.send(err)
    }

})

module.exports= router;
```